# Creating new items to put in a list (like the phonebook) iPhone SDK?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Let's say I want to create an app that lets add people to a list (like the phone book). And within this app I'm able to put how many cars this person has and what color it is.

Coming from a C++ background, the logical thing to do is create a linked list with all of of this info. If I wanted to know how many blue cars my friends have, I could use an iterator to count how many blue cars there are.

Would I use the same concept in objective-c? I want to be able to have the little 'plus' sign at the top, right-hand corner of the screen so that I could keep adding people to my list. So my first issue is making this happen. I created a storyboard to make the basics happen. My follow-up issue would be to iterate through the list and count how many 'blue' cars there are.

I'm not asking for code here... I'm asking for concepts. How would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Use an NSMutableArray which is kindof like a vector in c++. It's not neccessary with a linked list. If you want it twodimensional simply use a NSMutableDictionary which works like a map in c++.

Answer (score 0):

yes here if you can handle global `NSMutableArray` with its key then it is possible here.....
now as a example if you have people name with name key and also another key with car then when you click on plus sign you add the record in your another error and at last you commit your data with final array....
hope,help it.....
:)